# Cleanup wiki tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Just noticed we've got a bunch of `*wiki*` tags:

- [wiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiki) and [mediawiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki): makes sense to keep them both, as the first will be used to ask for "any wiki" – while the second fits e.g. requests concerning mediawiki extensions
- [wikivoyage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikivoyage): seems to make sense taking a look at the questions using it: pretty specific to tools supporting that open-source project
- [wikimedia](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia) (× 2), [wikimedia-commons](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia-commons) (× 4) and [wikidata](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikidata) (× 3) look like they all addressing the same realm. Do we really need 3 tags here?

**Suggestion:** keep all from the first two groups – but merge the 3 tags of the last group.

Opinions?

Comment: Makes sense to me, but I'd like to have Nicolas Raoul's opinion, since he seems to be our most active regular around these tags. There may be a good reason to have separate tags for separate areas of Wikimedia (such as Wikivoyage).

Comment: Fine with me, @Gilles – that's why I brought it up here on Meta instead of simply re-tagging the few candidates :) In fact I could see what could make the `*commons` tag special (as wiki-commons deals with media and not with the articles themselves) – though I don't see that justifies a separate tag (currently). So good point to wait for Nicolas (maybe you could `@@ping` him to check here? I can't, not being a mod).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am indeed very familiar with all of these projects. While they might sound excessively related, most are as unrelated as two different Adobe products.

Everything being open, each site has its own community of developers and its own crazy amount of custom tools, most of them unadvertised and hard to find.

I support keeping all of the tags mentioned in the question.

Individual sites:

- [wikivoyage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikivoyage): Tools specifically for Wikivoyage
- [wikimedia-commons](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia-commons): Tools specifically for Commons, one of the world's largest media repository. Most Commons editors use desktop and mobile tools for media upload/management
- [wikidata](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikidata): This one too is rich in custom tools. Wikidata is on the verge of becoming the pivot point for most data mashups projects, so I predict the number of tools and libraries related to it will continue to rise exponentially in the next few years

Other:

- [wiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiki): Any software that uses any kind of [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) syntax
- [mediawiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki): Extensions for the software called MediaWiki
- [wikimedia](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikimedia): This is an umbrella tag for all Wikimedia sites that do not have a tag yet, for instance Wiktionary, Wikipedia, etc. And also for the special tools/services that exist across these websites but not in the MediaWiki software

Comment: Sounds convincing, Nicolas (though only few questions use each tag currently). So if you're supporting to keep all of those tags, would you mind setting up the tag-wikis accordingly? `wikivoyage`, `wikidata` and `wikimedia-commons` lack tag-wikis and -excerpts completely currently. All of them set up and made clear would avoid future confusion :) A pointer to this Meta-Q from the `wiki` tag-wiki might be a good thought as well.

Comment: @Izzy: Done, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas! I've added a "related tags" section to the `wiki` tag-wiki, and linked to it from the "other" tag-wikis (so we just have one place to update in case more tags are added).

Comment: Also, using specific tags means that Wikidata or Commons experts can easily find and answer questions here even if they never check the site, simply with a filtered feed on stackexchange.com.